# I can't understand the grid system PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, desktop

I need to create some program that will calculate some thermodynamics properties. I write on macos, python 3 because python has the necessary library.

So i have the problem with GUI. I learn and try to create simple grid for my application, but the actual behavior of the elements is very different from the one conceived (or doesn't work). I don't understand how to create right grid for my app. When i studied bootstrap, i needed one evening for understanding, and after that i could to create grid very easy, but here is hell.

**Please help me. I want to understand how i need to create right grid system for my app**

my Application layout:

[image: my Application layout picture]

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you've tried so far, and why it isn't working?

Comment: It's much easier to understand how layouts work if you use [Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html).